# Travis: how to create a .tar file and retrieve its url?

Tags: heroku, travis-ci

I'm trying to create a tarball with `tar -czf ../tmp/server.tar.gz .` and I need to retrieve its url to deploy it to Heroku using `heroku builds:create --source-url https://...../tmp/server.tar.gz -a app-name`.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [source endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#source) in heroku's platform api to get URLs on which you can upload your file, and another address you can pass as source-url to the builds:create command.

However, that command, in the [heroku-builds plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds) will do this for you if you don't specify any URL.
So instead of tarring the code yourself, you can just do this:

> heroku builds:create

Which will do the tarring, uploading and triggering of the build for you.

If you don't wish to build the current directory, you can do the following:

> heroku builds:create --dir ../path/to/folder